# Error : LateInitializationError: Field '_startDate@934496985' has not been initialized and Set State

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, syncfusion

I am building a calendar through syncfusion calendar on a flutter app and I have been getting an error that tells me "Field '' has not been initialized". I know that I need to initialize _startDate and _endDate but I am not sure what value it should be given.

Code :

```
class EventCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventCalendar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  EventCalendarState createState() => EventCalendarState();
}

List<Color> _colorCollection = <Color>[];
List<String> _colorNames = <String>[];
int _selectedColorIndex = 0;
late DataSource _events;
Meeting? _selectedAppointment;
late DateTime _startDate;
late TimeOfDay _startTime;
late DateTime _endDate;
late TimeOfDay _endTime;
bool _isAllDay = false;
String _subject = '';
String _notes = '';

class EventCalendarState extends State<EventCalendar> {
  EventCalendarState();

  CalendarView _calendarView = CalendarView.month;
  late List<String> eventNameCollection;
  late List<Meeting> appointments;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _calendarView = CalendarView.month;
    appointments = getMeetingDetails();
    _events = DataSource(appointments);
    // initialize _startDate and _endDate here? 
    _selectedAppointment = null;
    _selectedColorIndex = 0;
    _subject = '';
    _notes = '';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: UserDrawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Itinerary',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.black)),
        ),
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
            child: getEventCalendar(_calendarView, _events, onCalendarTapped)),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF003893),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push<Widget>(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => EventEditor()),
                )));
  }

  SfCalendar getEventCalendar(
      CalendarView _calendarView,
      CalendarDataSource _calendarDataSource,
      CalendarTapCallback calendarTapCallback) {
    return SfCalendar(
      view: _calendarView,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
      todayHighlightColor: Color(0xFF003893),
      selectionDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white60),
      showNavigationArrow: true,
      cellBorderColor: Colors.transparent,
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      onTap: calendarTapCallback,
      allowedViews: [
        CalendarView.day,
        CalendarView.week,
        CalendarView.month,
        CalendarView.timelineWeek
      ],
      monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
          showAgenda: true,
          agendaViewHeight: 250,
          appointmentDisplayMode: MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment),
      dataSource: _calendarDataSource,
      initialDisplayDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
          DateTime.now().day, 0, 0, 0),
      timeSlotViewSettings: TimeSlotViewSettings(
          minimumAppointmentDuration: const Duration(minutes: 60)),
    );
  }

  void onCalendarViewChange(String value) {
    if (value == 'Day') {
      _calendarView = CalendarView.day;
    } else if (value == 'Week') {
      _calendarView = CalendarView.week;
    } else if (value == 'Month') {
      _calendarView = CalendarView.month;
    } else if (value == 'Timeline week') {
      _calendarView = CalendarView.timelineWeek;
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  void onCalendarTapped(CalendarTapDetails calendarTapDetails) {
    if (calendarTapDetails.targetElement != CalendarElement.appointment) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _selectedAppointment = null;
      _isAllDay = false;
      _selectedColorIndex = 0;
      _subject = '';
      _notes = '';
      if (_calendarView == CalendarView.month) {
        _calendarView = CalendarView.day;
      } else {
        if (calendarTapDetails.appointments != null &&
            calendarTapDetails.appointments!.length == 1) {
          final Meeting meetingDetails = calendarTapDetails.appointments![0];
          _startDate = meetingDetails.from;
          _endDate = meetingDetails.to;
          _isAllDay = meetingDetails.isAllDay;
          _selectedColorIndex =
              _colorCollection.indexOf(meetingDetails.background);
          _subject = meetingDetails.eventName == '(No title)'
              ? ''
              : meetingDetails.eventName;
          _notes = meetingDetails.description;
          _selectedAppointment = meetingDetails;
        } else {
          final DateTime date = calendarTapDetails.date!;
          _startDate = date;
          _endDate = date.add(const Duration(hours: 1));
        }
        _startTime =
            TimeOfDay(hour: _startDate.hour, minute: _startDate.minute);
        _endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: _endDate.hour, minute: _endDate.minute);
        Navigator.push<Widget>(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => EventEditor()),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  List<Meeting> getMeetingDetails() {
    final List<Meeting> meetingCollection = <Meeting>[];
    eventNameCollection = <String>[];
    eventNameCollection.add('');

    _colorCollection = <Color>[];
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF3D4FB5));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF0F8644));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF8B1FA9));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFD20100));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFFC571D));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF85461E));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFFF00FF));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFE47C73));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF636363));

    _colorNames = <String>[];
    _colorNames.add('Blue');
    _colorNames.add('Green');
    _colorNames.add('Purple');
    _colorNames.add('Red');
    _colorNames.add('Orange');
    _colorNames.add('Caramel');
    _colorNames.add('Magenta');
    _colorNames.add('Peach');
    _colorNames.add('Gray');

    return meetingCollection;
  }
}

class DataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  DataSource(List<Meeting> source) {
    appointments = source;
  }

  @override
  bool isAllDay(int index) => appointments![index].isAllDay;

  @override
  String getSubject(int index) => appointments![index].eventName;

  @override
  String getNotes(int index) => appointments![index].description;

  @override
  Color getColor(int index) => appointments![index].background;

  @override
  DateTime getStartTime(int index) => appointments![index].from;

  @override
  DateTime getEndTime(int index) => appointments![index].to;
}

class Meeting {
  Meeting(
      {required this.from,
      required this.to,
      this.background = Colors.green,
      this.isAllDay = false,
      this.eventName = '',
      this.description = ''});

  final String eventName;
  final DateTime from;
  final DateTime to;
  final Color background;
  final bool isAllDay;
  final String description;
}
```

On top of the error, when I go to another page and return back to this calendar page, whatever events that was saved on it earlier on disappears already.

What value should I be giving to initialize _startDate and _endDate and how do I save the state of the page?

Comment: change your startDate and endDate to `DateTime? _startDate;
 DateTime? _endDate;`

Comment: Hi, do I declare that in the init state or class EventCalendarState? I declared it in the class EventCalendarState but I got the error that the property '' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null' in the void onCalendarTapped(). Then added "!." to those properties too and I receive the initialization error again.

Answer (score 0):

All state properties must be declared inside `State` class. `late` means that such variable will be initialized later (for example in `initState` method). If initialization time is not known make variable nullable, I.e. use question mark for type (e.g. `DateTime?`.

Comment: Hi, I declared it in the class EventCalendarState but I got the error that the property '' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null' in the void onCalendarTapped(). Then added "!." to those properties too and I receive the same has not been initializated error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize `start` and `end` dates, to be able to accept null use `?`

like that

```
DateTime? _startDate;
DateTime? _endDate;
```

Comment: Hi, I declared it in EventCalendarState but I got the error that the property '' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null' for "_startDate.hour" etc. in void onCalendarTapped(). Added "!." to those properties but I receive the same initialization error.

Comment: so `_startDate!.hour! ` ?

Comment: As of now, it is : ```_startTime = TimeOfDay(hour: _startDate!.hour, minute: _startDate!.minute);
_endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: _endDate!.hour, minute: _endDate!.minute);``` But if I put the '!' after .hour too, it tells me that the '!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null.

Comment: For, ```_startDate!.hour!``` , the error is "'!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null. Try removing the '!'".

Comment: not this) ok try use `late` and put `DateTime.now()` to your startDate and endDate for example, and also remove `!`, what you'll get?

Comment: I do not get an error doing that. :) My event editor pops up and I can add an event. But if I try to change the date of the event, it only stays at ```DateTime.now()``` value, which is today's date so the event only adds an event that is on 8 October 2021.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them nullable, with DateTime? and before using them, where you got an error like when you want to access the hour property from them, you can check them if they are null, like this:

```
if([_startTime, _endTime].contains(null)) return;
```

Also, since you don't use the data outside of the handler and it is used after you change the value, you can initialize them with DateTime.now(), like this:

```
DateTime _startDate = DateTime.now();
```

And you can do this:

```
if (_calendarView == CalendarView.month) {
  _calendarView = CalendarView.day;
  return;
}
```

To remove the else that's coming after.

Comment: Hey, I tried to add that ```if([_startTime, _endTime].contains(null)) return;``` but I get an error that it expects a class member, an identifier and ).

Comment: try then: if(_startTime == null || _endTime == null) return;

Comment: I still get the same error. And just to be clear, I should put the condition within EventCalendarState class, just before @override and the initState?

Answer (score 0):

While specifying the variable as nullable we need to set the values before use them, in this case the **AppointmentEditor** class used the **_startDate** and **_endDate** values before initializing them, hence to use the values we must ensure that the values were set with values, hence before navigate to the editor page we must set values for the startDate and endDate variable with the required values, in this case you can use the selected date value from CalendarController or current date time value, or the date time value which you want to add the event in calendar.

In this shared code snippet, we have used current time value for the both variables as a default value, kindly set the **_startDate** and **_endDate** in the onPressed callback of the FloatingActionButton. Please find the attached code snippet for the same.

**Code snippet:**

```
onPressed: () {
_startDate??=DateTime.now();
_endDate??=DateTime.now();
 Navigator.push<Widget>(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AppointmentEditor()),
)
}
```